# Spark: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist in copyMerge

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-csv

I am trying to merge all spark output part files in a directory and create a single file in Scala.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit =  {
   val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
   val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
   FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), true, hadoopConfig, null) 
   // the "true" setting deletes the source files once they are merged into the new output
}
```

And then at last step, I am writing data frame output like below.

```
dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(10).write.partitionBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save(outputfile)
  merge(mergeFindGlob, mergedFileName )
  dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.unpersist()
```

When I run this I get below exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs:/user/zeppelin/FinancialLineItem/temp_FinancialLineItem
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
```

This is how I get my output

[image]

Instead of the folder, I want to merge all files inside a folder and create a single file.

Comment: I would suggest you not to create so many part files when you needed only one. your way is creating two separate tasks : first creating part files and then second to merge them all. why don't you combine all of them into one task ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan if i create less part files then my job becomes very slow ..So you are suggesting to create another scala job to merge all part files?Then again i have 33 such jobs ...

Comment: why are you merging them ? If you required them to be merged then I would suggest you to use scripting.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan That is client requirement and they are stick to that ..How do we use scripting to merge all files in a folders ...I will have 5K such folders

Comment: use the scripting language you are good with. bash or python or something else. and just call it from within your job.

Comment: If you don't want the folders, then don't use `partitionBy` while writing your dataframe.

Comment: @philantrovert then how can i partition my records based on columns

Comment: @RameshMaharjan is there anyway to rename the spark output files ..If i dont do mergeing then i will have huge no of files like more than 50K files ..How can rename the part file ?

Comment: there should be a way but I haven't done that yet. what happened with the scripting way?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan just managing client to accept pat files for now if they are very much adamant then i will go for next option..

Comment: did you try with coalesce ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan coalesce makes spark job very slow ..I tried it was working for smaller file but there are some files that has size of 19 GB also

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Also this merge technique will not work for gzip file ..I have to apply for unzipped files which will take lot more space .

Answer (score 0):

There is a copyMerge API in Hadoop 2 :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#line.382

Unfortunately this is going to be deprecated and removed in Hadoop 3.0.

Here's re-implementation of copyMerge (in PySpark though) I had to write as we couldn't find a better solution:
https://github.com/Tagar/stuff/blob/master/copyMerge.py

Hope it helps somebody else too.